# Can't go into object defined by rollup plugin-replace

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3

In a Svelte component, I'm trying to access an object I set up in my rollup config file.
My `rollup.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

...
export default {
...
    replace({
        foo: JSON.stringify({ bar: 'Hello' }),
    }),

...
```

In my Svelte component, a simple `console.log(foo)` works:

[image: foo]

But when I try to go into that foo object like `console.log(foo.bar)`, I get *foo is not defined*:

[image: fooUndefined]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! The object foo remains undefined so it is throwing the right error, and is unable to find `foo` to replace with whatever you are going to replace it with.

The solution is having the replace plugin do its job. You may access your variable like this in your `js` or your `.svelte` files

```js
const { bar } = foo;

console.log(bar);
```

Note: there was a change made to this plugin check [here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace#preventassignment) for details. if you are planning to use environment variables using dotenv consider

```js
import { config } from "dotenv";

...
replace({
      values: {
        foo: JSON.stringify({ bar: "Hello", ...config().parsed }),
      },
    }),
...
```

and in your svelte file

```js
  const { bar, ...rest } = foo;
  console.log("bar=>", bar);
  console.log("env=>", rest);
```

Comment: It works indeed. Interesting... Although I don't understand why destructing the `foo` object solves the issue.

Comment: The replace plugin is looking for `foo` and is unable to do so if it is `foo.bar`.

Answer (score 3):

This section of the document explains your exact problem.
https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/replace#delimiters

The `delimiters` option controls how the strings will be matched. With the default `delimiters` being `['\b', '\b(?!\.)']`, it would only replace `foo` if it follows a word boundary and is followed by a word boundary that is not a dot. Hence with your `rollup.config.js` the behaviour would be

```js
console.log(foo)
// becomes
console.log({"bar":"Hello"})

console.log(foo.bar)
// is not replaced by the plugin as `foo` IS followed by a dot

console.log(foo['bar'])
console.log(foo .bar) // space after `foo`
// both satisfy the delimiter check again and print: Hello
// (horrible coding style in the latter but to illustrate how it works)

const { bar } = foo
// also satisfy the delimiter check hence
console.log(bar) // prints: Hello
```

As you see, the replace plugin doesn't really parse your code but instead only preforms simple text replacement not too different from the search-and-replace feature of your IDE/editor. Gauss what would it say below?

```js
console.log('foo')
// Guess what?
// ...
// ...
// printed: {"bar":"Hello"}
// as if it were
console.log('{"bar":"Hello"}')
```

To conclude, your workaround might be

- `foo['bar']`,
- `const { bar } = foo`,
- avoid object replacement and use keys like `__FOO_BAR__`, `__FOO_BAZ__`, ...
- pass `delimiters: ['\\b', '\\b']` to allow dots following the key.

(However at the moment of writing, the last one doesn't seem to work yet due to a bugfix waiting to be merged).
https://github.com/rollup/plugins/pull/1088

If you use `delimiters: ['', '']` the earlier caveat requires much higher level of caution. Even a string literal `'food'` or a HTML template tag `<footer>` might be changed to gibberish like `'{"bar":"Hello"}d'` or `<{"bar":"Hello"}ter>`. So name your keys wisely or use some unusual delimiters depending on your usage, like what the old version of the plugin once demonstrated: `delimiters: ['<@', '@>']`.
https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace

Nevertheless since these kind of preprocessing is pretty rudimentary, care is always needed when adding replaced keys and when using them.